# Multiple Outer joins return top result

Tags: sql, sql-server, outer-join

I have a query with several left outer joins, for simplicity sake I will just include the two. It looks something like this:

```
SELECT Object.ID, Gloss.name, Gloss.order, Title.name from Object
LEFT OUTER JOIN Gloss on Gloss.object_id = Object.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Title on Title.object_id = Object.ID
```

However, some items have multiple Gloss, and I want to return only a single row with either the max or min Gloss.order. A sample output from my query looks like this:

```
|Object.ID | Gloss.name | Gloss.order | Title.name
|4.00      | glossvalue1| 1           | TitleValue
|4.00      | glossvalue2| 2           | TitleValue
|3.00      | gloss3-1   | 11          | OtherTitle
|3.00      | gloss3-2   | 13          | OtherTitle
|3.00      | gloss3-3   | 15          | OtherTitle
```

Ideally, I would like to return something like this:

```
|Object.ID | Gloss.name | Gloss.order | Title.name
|4.00      | glossvalue1| 1           | TitleValue
|3.00      | gloss3-1   | 11          | OtherTitle
```

I think I need some max or min things, but I am having trouble combining that with the other outer join (which does not need max or min).
Any help is appreciated, let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT Object.ID, (SELECT name FROM Gloss G WHERE G.object_id = X.object_id AND G.order = X.ord) AS [GlossName],
    X.order, Title.name 
FROM Object
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT object_id, MIN(order) ord FROM Gloss GROUP BY object_id) X
ON X.object_id = Object.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Title on Title.object_id = Object.ID
```

I didn't want to take min gloss name as I understood your min should be based on gloss order.

Comment: First I got "No column name was specified for column 2 of 'X' error and then changed `MIN(order` to `MIN(order) ord` and `X.order` from the SELECT to `x.ord` and I was in business. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Object.ID, min(Gloss.name), min(Gloss.order), Title.name from Object
LEFT OUTER JOIN Gloss on Gloss.object_id = Object.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Title on Title.object_id = Object.ID
GROUP BY Object.ID,Title.name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select object.ID, Gloss.name, min(Gloss.order) as order, Title.name
from object
left outer join Gloss on Gloss.object_id = object.ID
left outer join Title on Title.object_id = object.ID
group by object.ID, Gloss.name, Title.name
```