# Multiple outer join return one result

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I have a query where I perform three left outer joins, but I'd like to return only one result.

I asked this question awhile back:
[Multiple Outer joins return top result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994073/multiple-outer-joins-return-top-result)

Adding to that, I am having trouble returning the top row that is several joins away.

For example:

```
obj

|id    |  name  |
 1     |  bear  |
 2     |  cat   |
 3     |  moose |


obj_cn

|id    | obj_id | lex_id | ord
| 1    |  2     |  1     |  3
| 2    |  2     |  2     |  2
| 3    |  2     |  3     |  1
| 4    |  1     |  4     |  1

lex

| id   | trm_id |
| 1    |  2     |
| 2    |  1     |
| 3    |  4     |
| 4    |  3     |

trm

| id   | trm |
| 1    | puma|
| 2    | lion|
| 3    | brn |
| 4    |  cgr|
```

Ideally, I would like to return the lowest ordered term, along with other columns in the objtermktr table (and other joins, this example is simplified).

```
results

|id    | name   | trm
|1     | bear   | brn
|2     | cat    | cgr
|3     | moose  | NULL
```

My initial idea was to build off of the aforementioned question, but I am having trouble comparing across multiple joins without either returning a NULL value for trm or returning object id 2 three times (once for each term).

This query doesn't work, but here's sort of what I was trying

```
SELECT id, name ,
,(select trm from trm t where t.id = a.id and r.ord=a.ord7) as term
from obj

left outer join
(select obj_id, lex_id, MIN(ord) ord7 from obj_cn group by obj_id, lex_id) a
on obj.id = a.obj_id

left outer join lex on a.lex_id = lex.trm_id
left outer join trm on lex.trm_id = trm.id)
```

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks for reading!

UPDATE: I didn't make this database and cannot restructure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps a lot if you include CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

```
create table obj (
  id integer primary key,
  name varchar(10) not null unique
  );

insert into obj values
(1, 'bear'),
(2, 'cat'),
(3, 'moose');

create table trm (
  id integer primary key,
  trm varchar(10) not null unique
  );

insert into trm values
(1, 'puma'),
(2, 'lion'),
(3, 'brn'),
(4, 'cgr');

create table lex (
  id integer primary key,
  trm_id integer not null 
    references trm (id)
);

insert into lex values
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(3, 4),
(4, 3);

create table obj_cn (
  id integer primary key,
  obj_id integer not null
    references obj (id),
  lex_id integer not null
    references lex (id),
  ord integer not null
    check (ord > 0),
  unique (obj_id, lex_id)
);

insert into obj_cn values
(1, 2, 1, 3),
(2, 2, 2, 2),
(3, 2, 3, 1),
(4, 1, 4, 1);
```

> Ideally, I would like to return the lowest ordered term, along with
>   other columns in the objtermktr table (and other joins, this example
>   is simplified).

It *sounds* like this gives you the lowest ordered term.

```
select obj_id, min(ord) as ord
from obj_cn
group by obj_id;
```

This slightly more complex version will preserve all the rows in the "obj" table, which you'll need in order to get the result set you want.

```
select obj.id as obj_id, min(ord) as ord
from obj
left join obj_cn on obj.id = obj_cn.obj_id
group by obj.id
```

You can use either of those derived tables in a join (or in multiple joins) on "obj_id" or on both "obj_id" and "ord". In the example below, I use the second of statement (above) in a common table expression, and join on both columns.

```
with min_ords as (
  select obj.id as obj_id, min(ord) as ord
  from obj
  left join obj_cn on obj.id = obj_cn.obj_id
  group by obj.id
)
select obj.id, obj.name, trm.trm
from obj
left join min_ords on min_ords.obj_id = obj.id 
left join obj_cn on obj_cn.obj_id = obj.id and obj_cn.ord = min_ords.ord
left join lex on lex.id = obj_cn.lex_id
left join trm on trm.id = lex.trm_id
order by id

1  bear   brn
2  cat    cgr
3  moose
```

---

Since you surely have a unique constraint on obj.name and trm.trm, you could radically simplify your life by restructuring the obj_cn table. Reference "name" and "trm" directly. (I'm ignoring the "lex" table, the purpose of which is simply baffling.)

```
name   trm   ord
--
cat    lion  3
cat    puma  2
cat    cgr   1
bear   brn   1
```

Depending on the purpose, you might not need *any* joins for some queries that target that table.

Comment: Thanks, and I understand what you mean about baffling structure. However I do not have the luxury of restructuring the database, just the fun of getting data out of it.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't even think about derived tables. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Arg, I was putting the join in the wrong place. Still learning...

```
select obj.id, obj.name,
 (select trm.trm  from obj_cn F
 left outer join lex on f.lex_id = lex.id
 left outer join trm on lex.trm_id = trm.id
 where f.obj_id=C.obj_id and f.ord=C.ord7)

from obj

left outer join (select obj_id, MIN(ord) ord7 from obj_cn group by obj_id) C
on obj.id = C.obj_id
```

Hope this helps someone!